# Как узнать количество установок приложения?

Tags: android

Работаю над приложением в Android Studio. Приложение не собираюсь публиковать в Google Market. Как собирать статистику по установке приложения? Нужно знать только количество установок по времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно подключить какую-нибудь аналитику, начиная от Google Analytics, Yandex Kit, Unity Analytics, заканчивая Flurry. 
Но самый простой способ, это просто отправлять запрос на сервер с информацией о первой установке. А на сервере эту информацию уже и считать нужным образом: общее количество установок и количество установок по времени.

Comment: Я собирался как раз использовать Flurry для контроля над сбоями приложения. Если в ней есть и статистика установок, тогда это наиболее приемлимый вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Храните в приложении флаг, который будет указывать первый ли раз приложение запускается или нет. Если первый раз, то делайте на сервер запрос, и увеличивайте счетчик установки. Так же желательно хранить флаг успешной отправки на сервер запроса, что бы не потерять установку при отсутствии интернета на устройстве.

Answer (score 2):

Используй вот этот сервис [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) - полный отчет об установках (общие, за день и т.д.), отчет не только об установках, но и о том сколько человек пользовались вашим приложением и очень много другой статистики.

Заодно подключи Crashlytics - будешь получать отчеты по сбоям (+ стэктрэйс)

Comment: Благодарю, ответ очень полезен.

Answer (score 1):

При первом запуске приложения отправлять на свой сервер информацию об установке